# Can't set CORS headers

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have enabled CORS for rest endpoint and I need to add a header to the 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' header.

```
public void configure() {
    restConfiguration().component("netty4-http").bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
    .contextPath("/").port(8099)
    .enableCORS(true)
    .corsAllowCredentials(true)
    .corsHeaderProperty("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization");
```

Unfortunately the response does not reflect these settings (Authorization header is missing):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers → Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Methods → GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, CONNECT, PATCH
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Access-Control-Max-Age → 3600
```

I cannot find out why the header can't be set by '.corsHeaderProperty()'.
Any help is very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Please add a `System.out.println("Set cors-headers by config()");` as the last command in `public void configure` and check if the output arrives the console.

Comment: @PeterRader I don't quit understand how that helps, but yes if I add a print statement it reaches the console.

Comment: Only to see if the configuration gets effective.